# How can i show the updates is available for the installed apps in android

Tags: android

I want to check in android device for the updates available for the all the installed apps in device.
I want to implement the like this from play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.goddchen.android.x.appupdate&hl=en

Can i show the list of available update apps ?
please anybody help about , I have try https://42matters.com/api about its tacking too much time for showing updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code this works fine:

**Code to check whether update available:**

```
private class checkUpdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        String curVersion = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        String newVersion = curVersion;
        newVersion = Jsoup
                .connect(
                        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                + getPackageName() + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com").get()
                .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]").first().ownText();
        update= (value(curVersion) < value(newVersion)) ? true : false;
        if(update){
             /* Post a Handler for the UI to pick up and open the Dialog */
            mHandler.post(showUpdate);
            //update= false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        update= false;
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

**This Runnable creates a Dialog and asks the user to open the Market :**

```
 private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(HomePageActivity.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.appicon)
        .setTitle("Update Available")
        .setMessage("An update for is available. Open Android Market and see the details?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    String id = activity.getApplicationInfo().packageName;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + id));
                        startActivity(intent);
                }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked Cancel */
                }
        })
        .show();
       }
};
```

Comment: hi, its good for the a update of one  application , but i want to check for all the application installed in device.

Comment: @user3122596 you can do it by checkUpdate this. You just only get the app names or packages and stores in your List. And run all the apps in  while loop which is running in your device. And at the you can show the list. But before that you should have all the app list running in your device